# Definition of asymptote

Tags: calculus, algebraic-geometry

I understand that the asymptote to a curve is a straight line such that the distance between the curve and the line tends to zero as they tend to infinity. However many books also say that an asymptote is a straight line which meets the curve at two coincident points at infinity. My doubts are:

1. I can't understand the second definition. What does meeting the curve at infinity mean? What does two coincident points at infinity mean?
2. How are these two definitions equivalent?

I will be grateful if someone clarifies my doubts.

Thanks

Comment: In infinity, the distance between the line and the asymptote is 0, as you state. When the distance is 0, two lines touch/intersect.

Comment: Think of projective curves.

Comment: Check: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote

Comment: I find it hard to believe that any book would give that second definition. Please give a specific source, and copy out the exact wording, and then we'll talk.

Comment: See the first line of the article here: http://www.jstor.org/pss/3602113 I can't access the full article so I can't unfortunately read what the author has to say about 2 points. Whaat I want is a formal understanding of "two points". Is it that for the curve y=f(x) and the line y=mx+b; 1/(f(x)-mx-b) has a double root at zero or something like that?

Comment: The distance between a curve and any line is what it is, a non-negative real number and it doesn't tend to anything. It is zero if the line is an asymptote but the converse is completely false: think of two intersecting lines. Actually, the definition of asymptote is not so easy as it looks.

Comment: @ George Elencwajg: Well, technically speaking I assumed the definition talked of the limit of shortest distance between a point P on the line and the curve as P is moved in a specific direction. But this too seems sort of informal. How do you define an asymptote?

Comment: Dear @Shahab, I don't define asymptotes because  the concept is useless for what I do. Moreover I have noticed that many books that claim to define them actually make mistakes when they try to use them, because their formal definition  doesn't make sense (like in the book you quote) or doesn't correspond to what they actually want to express . In the unlikely case that I *had* to define "asymptote" I would indeed say that it is a line passing through a point at infinity of some extension of the curve in projective space $\mathbb P^2(\mathbb R)$, but I didn't and won't check the details.

Comment: You didn't give a book that gives your second definition. What you gave is an article, from 1926, that claims, although it doesn't give any references, that "according to the standard text-books, an asymptote is a line which meets a curve at two points at infinity, but is not wholly at infinity." The author goes on to criticize that definition. In any event, we have come a long way since 1926, and I don't think you'll find your second definition in any books today.

Comment: @ Gerry Myerson: [Here](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=sUxh92r_YW8C&pg=PA853&dq=asymptote+meets+the+curve+at+two+points+at+infinity&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ijFDT6eFAZDSrQfI3KXABw&ved=0CEAQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=asymptote%20meets%20the%20curve%20at%20two%20points%20at%20infinity&f=false) is a book which carries this definition.

Comment: Ha! That book says, "Thus it is **incorrect** to define an asymptote as the straight line which cuts the curve in two points at infinity." I wouldn't say it carries the definition - I'd say it refutes the definition!

Comment: Its refutation is followed by what it terms as a correct "definition", which says that an asymptote is a straight line which is a finite distance from the origin (I considered the line being a finite distance away implicit) which meets the curve at two coincident points at infinity. This was my second definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what confuses is the fact that the definition in the book is just an informal way of saying what you said (modulo the line meeting the curve in **2**  points - I'll get to that immediatly): In my expreience a lot of calculus books are deliberately imprecise so as not to frighten the student with technical definition and thus give first a definition which is supposed to appeal to the intuition. We could state the definition of an asymptote at different levels which vary in rigor and formalism. Thus we could have:

Less precise (at an essential point) and informal - your definition: "The asymptote to a curve is a straight line such that the distance between the curve and the line tends to zero as they tend to infinity" (Lack of precision concerning whether you meant only $+\infty$ or not and if not, if you meant "they tend to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$" or they tend to $ +\infty$ and $ -\infty$")

Less precise (at a not so essential point) and informal - The books definition: "An asymptote is a straight line which meets the curve at two coincident points at infinity" (Lack of precision concerning how to rigorously translate "meets the curve" into a mathematical statement)

More precise and semi-formal - [Wikipedia's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote#Vertical_asymptotes) definition. Note that to be formal, one has to distinguish many cases in which the graph of the function could behave. Also note that in that definition arbitrary curves are excluded, since these can be rather monstruous and to ask for an asymptote for such a thing wouldn't make sense; see for example [this thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_cur) ].

Note further that 1) the more formal you get, the more context you have to specify (which in the other cases is implicitly assumed. Example: You were only talking about curves of graphs of functions on arbitrary curves in $\mathbb{R}^2$) 2) these 3 levels aren't by far the only ones; one could insert many levels of rigor/formalism between these three and there would also by room. 3) definitions aren't carved in stone; different authors use slightly different definitions (which mostly vary in technicalities; the underlying intuition is almost always the same).

To address the last problem (of the first question) concerning the line meeting the curve in 2 points: This is a special case  of the note 3) from above: Some authors state their one definition for various reasons. My guess, as to why the author required that the line should meet the curve in 2 points at infinity, is, again, that he wants to remain intuitive - and this definition of an asymptote just does that. The graph of the other answer illustrates this: the line given by all the point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that satisfy the equation $y=0$ is, in his definition, an asymptote, which would also be clear by just looking at the graph (which accounts for the intuitiveness of the definition). Usually asymptotes are defined like in your definition, where one is only concerned if the line is "close enough" to the function graph either at $t \rightarrow +\infty$ (I have namend the variable of your function $t$) **or**   $t \rightarrow -\infty$ (instead of $t \rightarrow +\infty$ **and**   $t \rightarrow -\infty$ like in the books version), but then you would have examples of functions and lines, where the line is an asymptote to the function, but the resulting picture isn't so nice anymore, since the line would approximate" the function nicely only for, say,  $t\rightarrow +\infty$.

After all this it, you should be now aware, that your definition is a little bit to vague , since you haven't specified if you meant with "infinity" only the positive infinity. If you did, the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

1. If the distance between the curve and the asymptote tends to infinity, where will they meet? Consider the following: $x\times y=1$. The graph is a [rectangular hyperbola](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RectangularHyperbola.html).

As you can see, the difference between the curve and the X/Y axis goes on reducing but it will never be 0. Or in other words, it will be 0 only at infinity.

[image: R. Hyperbola]

To make things clear : Take an example: You have 10 bucks, Every hour I will take half of them away from you. You start with 10. After an hour, you will have 5, Then 2.5, Then 1.25 and so on. When will you have 0 (not approx 0, "actual" 0) ?

The answer is at time $t = \infty$.

Also, what is happening to the difference between how much money you have and 0 ? They go on reducing and "try" to become 0 (but never will).

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

You ask, in the comments, for a formal understanding of "two points". I don't think this is possible, since I don't think "two points" makes sense. The line $y=0$ is an asymptote to the curve $y=e^x$; I can see using the language of projective geometry to say that the line meets the curve at a point at infinity, but I cannot see any interpretation under which the line meets the curve at two points at infinity.

Comment: On the wikipedia article on asympototes it is stated: "A plane curve of degree n intersects its asymptote at most at n−2 other points, by Bézout's theorem, as the intersection at infinity is of multiplicity at least two." Do you think this has something to do with this?

Comment: Maybe so. Of course, when you talk about "plane curve of degree $n$" you are talking about polynomial equations, so this does not apply to the $e^x$ example. Also, note in your quote the phrase *at least*. That means we might be talking about two "coincident" points, but we might be talking about more than two.

Answer (score 0):

After reading all the answers and searching for a bit on the web I think I have found on the correct solution. I am grateful to everyone who responded. I don't think both definitions are mathematically formal. The first conveys the idea that the asymptote is a line which kisses the curve at infinity or in other words is a tangent to the curve at infinity.

The second "definition" essentially says that the tangent to the curve at infinity is of multiplicity two (The definition is silent on whether it may be more). I found [this result](http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/~franz/ag05/ag-06.pdf) (Proposition 6.0.3) on the internet which says that with a proper understanding of "multiplicity" at an intersection point the tangent and the curve always have multiplicity at least two. So the second statement conveys the same idea with the addition of multiplicity at the intersection.